# imageViewをアニメーションさせながら効果音を流したい

Tags: objective-c, xcode

playボタンを押すと指定した数のimageViewが順番にアニメーションします。それと同時にそれぞれのアニメーションに合わせて効果音が鳴るようにしたいです。
しかし、現時点では音がimageViewの個数分なってからアニメーションが順番に始まります。

調べても分からなかったので質問させていただきました。
よろしくお願い致します。

【ViewController.m】

```
-(IBAction)play:(id)sender {

    for(i = 0;i < repeatCount;i++){ //iは指定したimageViewの番号

        [self animation];
        [clapInstance repeatClap:repeatCount];
    }
}


-(void)animation{

    //ここまではUIImageviewのimageViewを生成（省略）

    // アニメーション
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
                          delay:0.1f + 0.5f * i
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 550);

                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     }];
}
```

【Clap.m】

```
-(void)repeatClap:(int)repeatCount {

    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
    usleep(500000);

}
```